# Create polygon of buildings from Quickbird images in QGIS

Tags: qgis, feature-extraction

I have Quickbird/Ikonos/GeoEye image and want to extract all the buildings from the image as an independent layer in QGIS.
How can i achieve that?

Comment: Do you *also* have access to high resolution elevation data for the urban area of interest?

Answer (score 3):

There are only two ways to extract information like this.  One thing you have to remember is that a "building" in a satellite image is an interpretation by a human.  The buildings are a collection of pixels.  If you are looking to do this in a batch/automated way, you will want to classify the image.  QGIS has plugins to do this, such as Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin.  The remaining option are manual.  You can heads-up digitize the buildings using a polygon.

Answer (score 0):

The [Mahalanobis distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) classifier can be good at this sort of thing. Check out the [IPLER](http://ipler.cis.rit.edu/projects/haiti) site from the Rochester Institute of Technology. They did some interesting work identifying blue tarps in satellite imagery as a means to detect IDP (internally displaced persons) camps after the 2010 earthquake.

At the bottom of the IPLER page there is a description of the project.